# UnsatisfiableError when using conda install PyAudio

Tags: python, conda

When I do `conda install PyAudio`, this error comes up in my terminal. My Python version is Python 3.10.7.

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2> conda --version
conda 4.12.0
PS C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2> conda install PyAudio      
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abor| 
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pyaudio -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

Your python: python=3.9

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

Comment: `python -m pip install pyaudio`?

Comment: You are installing pyaudio into a Python version 3.9 per the line of your error report which states "Your python: python=3.9"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message informs you that Python version 3.9 is incompatible with PyAudio. Python v3.9 appears to be the version installed in your environment, not v3.10.7 as you stated. It appears that v3.10.7 would be compatible.

With Anaconda, three options stand out:

1. Open an Anaconda prompt, ensure you have the environment with Python v3.10.7 activated.
2. Switch your environment to the one using Python v3.10.7.
3. Use Anaconda to create a new environment and configure it with a compatible version of Python for PyAudio.

Option 1 & 2: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment.

Option 3 Can be accomplished using Navigator or via the [Anaconda Prompt](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

NOTE:

1. Ensure you choose one of the compatible Python versions from the list in the error message.

> - pyaudio -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

2. If you change or create a new environment, you will need to reinstall any package you want to use. Check with

```
conda list
```

3. There are other ways to manage environments, but exceed the scope of your issue.